# Sum number of observations in nested data

Tags: r

Ok, I'm not sure why I can't figure out how to do this. I know it has to be rather simple.

I have a large data frame consisting of schools (COMBOKEY) and school districts (LEAID). I need to get a count of the number of schools in each district, so that I can calculate the mean number of schools per district. Here's an example of how the data are structured:

```
COMBOKEY  LEAID
13745     1037
13747     1037
13753     1037
13756     1037
13757     1037
13760     1038
13761     1038
13762     1039
13763     1039
13770     1040
13771     1040
13776     1041
13778     1041
13781     1041
13788     1043
13790     1043
```

Or, here's a sample in r code:

```
head(cbind(Tot_CRDC1$COMBOKEY, Tot_CRDC1$LEAID))

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    1
[3,]    3    1
[4,]    7    2
[5,]    8    2
[6,]   11    2
```

Thanks so much for your patient help. In the meantime, I'll keep searching the forums for a solution that makes sense to my novice self, because I know this has had to have been answered a zillion different ways.

Here is an attempt with aggregate that is returning NAs:

```
head(aggregate(COMBOKEY ~ LEAID, Tot_CRDC1, mean, na.rm=TRUE))
    LEAID COMBOKEY
1 0100005       NA
2 0100006       NA
3 0100007       NA
4 0100008       NA
5 0100011       NA
6 0100013       NA
```

Comment: head(aggregate(COMBOKEY ~ LEAID, Tot_CRDC1, mean))
    LEAID COMBOKEY
1 0100005       NA
2 0100006       NA
3 0100007       NA
4 0100008       NA
5 0100011       NA
6 0100013       NA

Comment: I used that code and got NAs.

Comment: Are you sure you are spelling `COMB0KEY` correctly? In your posted comment you used two Os instead of one O and one 0.

Comment: This makes no sense.  Are you using two different data sets? Your LEAIDs are completely different

Comment: You're right, Richard. The example using aggregate is the actual data. The first one I posted I made up thinking it would be easier for some reason. I apologize for the misdirection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, every school is represented by one dataline, so what about table():

```
A<-table(LEAID)
mean(A)
```

Comment: Is there a weak to tweak this to obtain the harmonic mean? If this should be posted as a separate question, I can repost. Thanks.

Comment: library(psych); harmonic.mean(c(A))

Comment: This is working, but returning 0. The original mean was 3.59.

Comment: Not sure I get your problem now. The harmonic mean can be seen as a function of the arithmetic mean, so you can also use: `1/mean(1/c(A))`

Comment: Got it. Some lingering 0s were messing things up. Both of the answers you supplied: library(psych); harmonic.mean(c(A)) and 1/mean(1/c(A)) work perfectly. Thanks again.